# Cant save a data frame into csv which was read from an Excel in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I tried to read a file from excel using pandas  pd.io.excel.read_excel function. This read a file into a data frame df. Now this df when i tried to save into csv it saves only 826 rows out of ~3000 and also throws following error 'ascii' codec can't encode character at position * ord not in range(128). This also results in error output for merge operation.

The same merge gives correct result when file read from csv.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are using Python **2**, so `encoding` parameter of the [to_csv()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) function defaults to `ascii`:

> **encoding** : string, optional A string representing the encoding to use in the output file, defaults to ‘ascii’ on Python 2 and ‘utf-8’ on
>   Python 3.

so try this:

```
df.to_csv('/path/to/file.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Thanks alot, this is working perfectly fine and I can save the whole file into csv. But still the merge function is not working properly and giving inappropriate results.                                                                                  merged = pd.merge(pivot_down,df3, on=['attr1','attr2'], how='left')

Comment: @user3924957, Try always to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking questions. In case of _pandas_ questions please provide sample _input_ and _output_ data sets (5-7 rows in CSV/dict/JSON/Python code format _as text_, so one could use it when coding an answer for you). This will help to avoid _situations_ like: `your code isn't working for me` or `it doesn't work with my data`, etc.